# Write a query to find logged user

Tags: sql

I have a table "record" with the columns:

```
userId

ip

timestamp

userAgent
```

How do I write query that will list the userId and month for any occasions where a user logged in more than 10 times in a month?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your record table as an entry per login.  The query is relatively straight forward (here using PostgresSQL specific function for the month extraction):

```
select userId, date_trunc('month', timestamp) 'Month', count(*)
group by 1, 2
having count(*) > 10;
```

- MySQL would use `extract('YEAR_MONTH' from timestamp)`
- PostgreSQL uses `date_trunc('month', timestamp)` to extract a year/month
- SQLite3 would use `strftime('%Y-%m', timestamp)`

With MySQL you can leave out the count(*) from the select expression, others you hide it with a sub-query:

```
select userId, Month from (
   ...
 ) as t;
```